# Parameter "out" in numpy sum

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I try to initialize the result of a sum of two arrays using the parameters "out" and "where" to condition the rows to sum.

For two arrays a and b

```
a=np.array([1, 4, 2])
b=np.array([1, 0, 2])
```

I try to compute c with initial values of -5 for the rows where b is equal to 0:

```
c = np.sum([a, b], out=np.zeros_like(a)-5, where=b!=0, axis=0)
```

I suppose to obtain:

```
array([2, -5, 4])
```

but the result I got is:

```
array([2, 0, 4])
```

I think the function does not update the parameter "out" as it should. Could there be another mistake on my part?

Comment: I'm not a NumPy expert, but FWIW, you can get the result you want with `np.where(b!=0, a+b, -5)`

Comment: `np.sum` is `np.add.reduce` so it's use of `where` and `out` may be different from the plain `np.add`.  I haven't read its docs for this use, nor experimented with it.  `ufunc` `where/out` are most useful when you want to skip certain calculations so they don't give warnings like divide by 0.  For simplly substituting results, `np.where` is often good enough, and easier to use.

Comment: `sum` has an `initial` parameter, which is different from `out`.  It could be a scalar like `-5`.  `out` should be an array of the right shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `np.add` then the result will be as expected.

```
>>> c = np.add(a, b, out=np.zeros_like(a)-5, where=b!=0)
>>> c
array([ 2, -5,  4])
```

In the documentation of the `np.sum` I didn't find any statement like *Elsewhere, the out array will retain its original value* which is present in documentation of `np.add`. So it's look like a bug, but it's consistent with documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.sum` calculates the total first and then places the values in the memory location set by `out`. So it replaces [-5, -5, -5] with [2, 0, 4]. You can see this in action with this:

```
a = np.array([1, 4, 2])
b = np.array([1, 0, 2])

c = np.zeros_like(a) - 5

print(c)

np.sum([a, b], out=c, where=b != 0, axis=0)

print(c)
```

For your desired result, using `np.where` works:

```
c = np.where(b != 0, a+b, np.zeros_like(a) - 5)
```

Comment: Why `np.zeros_like(a) - 5` instead of just `-5`? I don't use NumPy much myself.

Comment: -5 works fine and is less verbose. I sort of just auto-piloted and used an array with the same shape.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake or confusion is because in the case of np.divide the "out" array retain the value.